# Android Logcat strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-studio

After Editing the LogCat the logical not working properly. I tried Invalidate and restart.Tried restarting logCat.But none working

Log.d("Error", "doInBackground:  Login Async" );

But Showing Only D/Error: doInBackground:

Comment: canary or stable build? If its canary I suggest you file a bug

Comment: @channae Stable Build